# Database codefirst entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm working on an ASP.NET project. I migrated my database named "youbay" with 
reverse engineering. It worked. My database contains tables (picture, user, product...) but when I try to change something on the code and then update my database it with code first other tables are then created named youbay.picture,youbay.user...

Answer (score 0):

What do you concretely mean with RE? Creating ASP.NET Models by guessing the mapped .NET types of the table scheme?  Maybe your db-structures are a bit different from the ones EF would genereate itself, so that EF will see a conflict. Or EF keep track of the changes itself, so he isn't touching the tables because he won't recognize that he created them.

Whatever happened, it seems like your way of migrating was not very clean. You should tell EF use an existing database like explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx). This will prevent conflicts and also save work/time, because EF will automatically generate your models based of the database-scheme. So no RE is needed.

Comment: Reverse engineering is a way to use an existing database to create your initial models, and from that point forward you use the code first approach.